# SSRS Query result in one cell based on other cells in the same row

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Have not yet had to do this in SSRS and I'm scratching my head.

Basically, I have a tablix based on DataSet 1.  The tablix is sorted and grouped on a field called AssemblyName and it is also the first column value.  The second column value is based on the sum of a field called Quantity. (in the database table, each row has an AssemblyName value and a Quantity value)

The tricky part is this:  There is another table in the database that contains a 'snapshot' of the AssemblyName and Quantity based on older (original) data.

And in my Tablix I want to show a cell in the same row that Sums the old Quantities for the AssemblyName in the first cell of the row.  The old Quantities would be pulled from the database table with the old data.

Basically, the goal is the show a Tablix grouped and sorted by AssemblyName, and have the following columns in the tablix: Assembly Name (from current DB table), the current Quantity sum (from current DB table), and the old Quantity sum (from another DB table with the old data).

I have everything working except for the cell that contains the old Quantity sum from the old DB table.

The old DB table is in the same database, so that is not an issue, what my problem is, creating a query that sums the Quantities in the old table based on the value of the AssemblyName in the same Tablix row.

I've tried creating Dataset 2 with a query based on parameters pulled from Dataset 1, and then writing this expression in the old quantity cell:

```
=Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "Dataset 2")
```

I'm getting blank values in every cell in the third column, which contains the expression above. I'm assuming it because the Dataset 2 is not actually reading the values of AssemblyName in the same tablix row.  The essence of what I want to do, however, is pass the value from the first column in the tablix, which contains AssemblyName, to the WHERE clause in the query for Dataset 2 whose parameter is in turn shown in the third column's cell in the same tablix row.

In case it helps, the query from DataSet 2 is as follows:

```
SELECT AssemblyName
, Quantity
FROM OldData
WHERE AssemblyName = @compare_AssemblyName
```

I hope this makes sense, but please ask questions as needed so that I can clarify.

Regards.

Comment: Perhaps I can sum the old quantities within the query for Dataset 1?

Comment: Can you show some sample data from both the data sets?

Comment: Have you tried Lookup? Something like this                                                        =LookUp(Fields!AssemblyName.Value,Fields!AssemblyName.Value,Fields!Quantity.Value,"dataset_oldvalue").

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pull the old data in along with your new data in the same query, then just sum the respective fields:

```
SELECT AssemblyName
    , NewQuantity = n.Quantity
    , OldQuantity = COALESCE(o.Quantity, 0)
FROM NewData n
    LEFT JOIN OldData o
        ON n.AssemblyName = o.AssemblyName
WHERE n.AssemblyName = @compare_AssemblyName
```